# Parse script is returning the whole text document and not the lines with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have a parsing script that seems to only be working with an IP address. Once I add a vserver or service name to the parsing script it returns the whole file. It is basically copying and pasting the whole file and not giving me the lines with the script. I think it is taking letters and moving them around and printing all lines that include the letters. Could someone please show me how to write a more concrete script that searches for the string exactly as it is in the quotes? Any help would be highly appreciate. I currently have the other search screens commented out. Thanks for reading,

```
lines = list()

with open("ns-batch.bak.txt", "r") as orig_file:
    for line in orig_file:
        if "192.168.1.133" in line: #or "LB_TEST_EXT_REDIRECT_TestConnect" in line: 
            lines.append(line)

with open("Hello1", "x") as new_file:
    for line in lines:
        new_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: `new_file.write(line)`, linefeed is included

Comment: Please include a sample of your source file and what exactly it is you're trying to achieve. It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: From your code and your title it appears that every line in orig_file contains the string "192.168.1.133". Can you make sure that your assumptions are all correct?

Comment: @mangoHero1 Please do not modify code in a question like that. No matter how trivial the change may seem to you, it can potentially invalidate the whole question. Formatting is fine, but altering whitespace in Python is most certainly not!

Comment: That being said, OP, please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: Calling `iter()` on a file object is [the same as repeatedly calling `file.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next). This assumes the contents of the file is delimited by newline characters. Test this with your file by manually calling `orig_file.next()` and see what you get.